# What would you call the time complexity of an algorithm of this sort?

Tags: c#, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, computer-science

I am using C# syntax but this question is not specific to C# only.

**Example 1**

```
public static long Do(long n)
{
    var sqrt = (long)Math.Sqrt(n);

    for(long i = 0; i < sqrt; i++)
        // do something

    return result;
}
```

Would that still be *linear time* even though even in the worst case, we're doing the operation for only the square root times of `n`, which is a very small fraction of `n`?

**Example 2**

And how would you classify the time-complexity of the algorithm below?

```
public static long Do(long n)
{
    while (n > 1)
    {
        n = (long)Math.Sqrt(n);

        // do something
    }

    return result;
}
```

Would this be called an operation done in *logarithmic time* in the worst case, even though we're, once again, not just halving the number of iterations each time but reducing them by an order of magnitude more than just the half.

Comment: If you are doing sqrt(n) operations, that would be O(sqrt(n)) complexity, why linear?

Comment: The first one is `O(n^(1/2))`. The second one is a little be tricky.

Comment: Is there a term for `O(sqrt(n))`?

Comment: O(sqrt(n)) is the "term" for O(sqrt(n))... not sure what else it would be. Also, in this example, watch out for "input size". Because you don't actually have _n_ elements, but an integer _n_, the time complexity is generally given in terms of the size of the input integer in bits (because Turing machines). Increasing the input size by one bit doubles _n_, making it take sqrt(2) more time -- and so by that measure this would be exponential, or O(sqrt(2) ^ n) (this "n" not being the same as your variable _n_)

Comment: In wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) it's named "fractional power"

Comment: @Evk: Awesome! Thank you. :-)

Comment: By the way, your second algorithm is not log(n) also. Instead, it's loglog(n)

Comment: Isn't the first case O(n^1/2) = O((2^|n|)^1/2)  =  O(2^(0.5|n|)) ?It is definitively exponential in the length of the encoding. And there is no reason to consider *n* itself as the free variable unless you want to consider Integer factorization a polynomial-time problem.

Comment: @MargaretBloom, can you expand more on this? As I see it - you perform sqrt(n) operations, so why is this exponential? But I'm not very experienced in this really.

Comment: @Evk It does *sqrt(n)* operations in the value of *n* (i.e. *n*=100 means 10 operations). But in the theory of complexity we measure complexity in term of the length of the encoding, this can be thought as the number of digits of *n*. This [Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-polynomial_time) explain the common pitfall. One can, of course, measure complexity relative to any quantity of choice at the cost of losing a meaningful interpretation.

Comment: @MargaretBloom thanks, with that help of that link I finally figured out what is meant.

Answer (score 1):

The first code snippet contains only one loop and a constant number of operations outside of this loop. If this loop iterates `k` times while each iteration takes `t` time, it's complexity is `O(kt)`. Here, `k` is equal to `sqrt(n)` which means that if the loop contains no non-constant time operations (say, if it does not contain nested loops or recurrent functions, etc), then this snippet time complexity is equal to `O(sqrt(n))` which is also written as `O(√n)`.

The fact that there's a loop here does not mean anything in terms of complexity. For example, the following code, having two nested loops, has a linear complexity:

```
int j = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    for (; j < n; ++j)
    {
        // A loop with constant-time operations and eventual breaks
    }
}
```

In this example, `i` goes from `0` to `n`, thus we spend `O(n)` time on increasing `i`. Similarly, `j` goes from `0` to `n`, and we do `O(n)` increments of `j` variable as well as `O(n)` iterations of the inner loop body. Since we have no other operations in this code, the total complexity is `O(n) + O(n) + O(n) = O(n)`.

To deal with the second example, I rewrite it in recursive manner:

```
int Do(int n)
{
    // Do something with constant-time compexity
    return n > 1 ? Do(sqrt(n)) : result;
}
```

Let us call time complexity of this example as `T(n)`. We can see that `T(n) = 1 + T(sqrt(n))` where the time of calculation of first part of this function (which is constant) is taken as a time unit. Solving this recursive equation gives us `T(n) = log log n` (the logarithm here is binary). Indeed, `1 + log log(sqrt(n)) = 1 + log ((log n) / 2) = 1 + log log n - 1 = log log n`. For asymptotic expressions it does not really matter which base of logarithm you use, since `log_a x = log_a b * log_b x = O(log_b x)`, that's why typically the logarithm base is omitted.

So, the complexities are: `O(√n)` and `O(log log n)`.

**UP**: To non-strictly estimate your complexities, one may use Excel or any other software tool for calculation. You need just build a table of numbers of operations for different values of `n` and try to guess a complexity rule. For example, for code snippet #2 from the question:

```
N  Operations  log n  log log n 
1       1        0        -  
2       2        1        0
4       3        2        1
16      4        4        2
256     5        8        3
65536   6        16       4
```

The correct answer is typically obvious from the table

Answer (score 0):

Complexity is measured with respect of the *length of the encoding of the problem instance*.
The problem in both snippets is fully described by the parameter *n*, so an instance is a string *<n>* that encodes *n*.
We can use any *non degenerate* encoding, a common choice in the literature is writing *n* in any numeric positional system.
For example if *n* is 13 we can use "13" or "1101" or "15" or "D" as *<n>*.

It is easy then to see than the length of *<n>*, here denoted as *|n|*, is *log(n)*.
It is *not exactly* *log(n)*, we need to know the base to give an exact length, however we *don't need an exact length function L(n)* that given *n* returns *|n|* exactly, we just an **O**(L(n)) as we will use big-O notation anyway.
We can change base to any log by multiplying by a constant, so using *L(n) = log(n)* would do.
However if we use don't specify the base when it comes to expressing *n* in function of *|n|* we can only say that *n = 2<sup>**O**(|n|)</sup>* which will make the formulas too crowded.
Since we loss no generality by specifying a base, we can choose base two, thereby *|n| = log<sub>2</sub>(n)* and *n = 2<sup>|n|</sup>* in the limit (as *n* grows).

You can refer to any introductory book on the theory of complexity if anything above is new to you.

### Snippet 1

To keep the analysis very simple, we suppose that each iteration take constant time.
Then the total times is the number of iterations which are *n<sup>1/2</sup>*.
Since *n<sup>1/2</sup> = 2<sup>|n|/2</sup>* we have that the time complexity is

> 2<sup>**O**(|n|)</sup>, Exponential

### Snippet 2

At the iteration *k* the original value of *n* has been reduced to *n<sup>1/(2k)</sup>*. We then want to find *k* such that

*n<sup>1/2<sup>k</sup></sup> ≤ 1*

so that the loop ends.
But that condition can never be satisfied for any finite value of *k* (prove this as an exercise).
However the partial result is cast to an integer, without reverting to the floor function we can just require *n<sup>1/2<sup>k</sup></sup> ≤ 2* since once *n<sup>1/2<sup>k</sup></sup>* is two, at the next iteration it will be cast to one.

*n<sup>1/2<sup>k</sup></sup> ≤ 2* => *n ≤ 2<sup>2<sup>k</sup></sup>* => *log<sub>2</sub>(log<sub>2</sub>(n)) ≤ k*

Since *log<sub>2</sub>(n)* is *log<sub>2</sub>(2<sup>|n|</sup>) = |n|* the time complexity is

> **O**(log<sub>2</sub>(|n|)), Logarithmic

---

More strong statements, in terms of big-tetha, can be made but that's left to the reader.

Answer (score 0):

**Linear Time:** means that for an input of size *n*, the time complexity will be proportional to *n* itself. In other words, time complexity for a problem of size *n* = k * *n* (Guess what quadratic time means? For an input of size *n*, the time to run is proportional to *n<sup>2</sup>*... of time complexity = c * *n<sup>2</sup>*)

- For your first snippet, for an input of size *n*, the running time will be proportional to sqrt(*n*). Therefore running time can be written as a * sqrt(*n*) which is not the same function as k * *n*. The word used to describe such proportionality is just *Square Root Relation*.
- For your second snippet, you keep taking the square root of *n* until it reduces to 1. The recurrence for that can be written as:

  - T(n)= T(sqrt(n)) + 1
  - To solve such a recurrence, take *n* = 2<sup>2<sup>i</sup></sup>. Now, *i* will actually be the number of times that code snippet will run, resulting in double log of *n* or Log(Log(n)) as the run time for this snippet.

---

<sup>*To solve your second snippet, I actually asked [this question on Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1952902/286229).*</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The first snippet has complexity `O(sqrt(n))`.

The second snippet has complexity `O(log(log(n))`. It only takes a little 10th grade algebra to solve the equation `n^1/(2^i) < 2` for `i`, which is the complexity of the second snippet.